# redux fetch body is not use with no cors mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch-api

I have this action which calls a function:

```
dispatch(Api({url: "my_url", method: "POST", data: data}))
```

Here I am passing array as a data..

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

export default function Api({url, method, headers, data}={}){
    return dispatch => {

        console.log(data)
        console.log(url)
        console.log(method)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
        let response = fetch(url, {
            mode: 'no-cors',
            method: method || null,
            body: data || null, 
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log("response");
             console.log(response)
            });

    }
}
```

Here I am using `fetch` with `mode:'no-cors'` I guess I am passing all the arguements.. My body here is simple array that I am passing as arguement..

When I see the response it is like :

```
body: null
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: "opaque"
url:""
```

Here my body is not being used..

What is wrong in here ? Need help

Comment: Have you got the answer to this ?Iam also facing similar issue...

Comment: yes the issue was on server side.. you should allow all origin to fetch

Comment: Yes that helped me. I have added <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />' in web config file.But i have changed to axios instead of 'isomorphic-fetch'

Answer (score 30):

You're getting an `opaque response` [[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/type)] [[2](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque)], because you're using fetch with `mode: 'no-cors'`.
You need to use `mode: 'cors'` and the server needs to send the required CORS headers [[3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers)] in order to access the response.

Comment: I have made to mode:'cors' and made necessary changes as mentioned in https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api. But getting response as (...)
bodyUsed:false
headers:Headers
ok:true
status:200
statusText:"OK"
type:"cors"
url:. Can you please help me to see the data?

Comment: Do you have a public URL for the service that I can test?

Comment: Sorry, Currently the api/url  is not hosted anywhere.