# successful fetch of api but no response

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am fetching a url using fetch in react redux application which looks like:

```
fetch(url, {
            mode: 'no-cors',
            method: method || null,
            headers: headers || null,
            body: form || null,
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log(response.status)
                console.log("response");
                console.log(response);
            }).then(function(data){
                console.log(data)
                console.log(data)
            })
```

Strange this is happening. When I call the url it is called and the response is 200. When I see in the console for response I am getting proper response from the url but `response.status` is giving me `0` and my `response` looks weird like:

`body: null
 ok: false` and so on...

I don't know what is wrong in here because my api is called and even I am getting response but I am unable to catch the response.

Is it I have to wait for api to complete and process further? Like waiting for fetch if yes then how can I do it?

Comment: Can you prove that it is a problem with `fetch` and not with the API itself?

Comment: Yes because in my network I can see the response from the API..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redux fetch body is not use with no cors mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169728/redux-fetch-body-is-not-use-with-no-cors-mode)

Answer (score 0):

There is no HTTP status code 0. What you see is a 0 returned by the library that you are using. You will have to check the documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending mode: 'cors'

in no-cors mode you will gat an opaque response