# fetch gives an empty response body

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have a react/redux application and I'm trying to do a simple GET request to a sever:

```
fetch('http://example.com/api/node', {
  mode: "no-cors",
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json"
  }
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response.body); // null
  return dispatch({
    type: "GET_CALL",
    response: response
  });
})
.catch(error => { console.log('request failed', error); });
```

The problem is that the response body is empty in the `.then()` function and  I'm not sure why. I checked examples online and it looks like my code should work so I'm obviously missing something here. 
The thing is, if I check the network tab in Chrome's dev tools, the request is made and I receive the data I'm looking for.

Can anybody shine a light on this one?

**EDIT:**

I tried converting the reponse.

using `.text()`:

```
fetch('http://example.com/api/node', {
  mode: "no-cors",
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json"
  }
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response); // returns empty string
  return dispatch({
    type: "GET_CALL",
    response: response
  });
})
.catch(error => { console.log('request failed', error); });
```

and with `.json()`:

```
fetch('http://example.com/api/node', {
  mode: "no-cors",
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json"
  }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response.body);
  return dispatch({
    type: "GET_CALL",
    response: response.body
  });
})
.catch(error => { console.log('request failed', error); }); // Syntax error: unexpected end of input
```

Looking in the chrome dev tools:

[image]

Answer (score 240, accepted):

I just ran into this. As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35291777/2800482), using `mode: "no-cors"` will give you an `opaque response`, which doesn't seem to return data in the body.

> opaque: Response for “no-cors” request to cross-origin resource.
>   [Severely restricted](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque).

In my case I was using `Express`. After I installed [cors for Express](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) and configured it and removed `mode: "no-cors"`, I was returned a promise. The response data will be in the promise, e.g.

```
fetch('http://example.com/api/node', {
  // mode: 'no-cors',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
},
).then(response => {
  if (response.ok) {
    response.json().then(json => {
      console.log(json);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: For me all that was required was adding `.then(json => {` onto the end of my `response.json()` statement. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeKellogg just a heads up that in case you want to keep your code tidy you can `return response.json()` and place the `.then(json=>` part between the last bracket and semicolon. `).then(json=>{});`

Comment: It seem if you leave off the domain and use a relative URI it works with ``no-cors``

Comment: I was using AWS API Gateway and in my lambda, I was missing this header ```"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"``` in the response. Adding that and removing ```no-cors``` worked for me.

Comment: For those who were hoping to leave the `no-cors` mode on in an attempt to bypass some CORS restrictions, unfortunately the opaque response that is returned from these types of requests cannot be parsed.  I was highly confused, because I could clearly see the correct response in my browsers developer tools, but it was never coming through to my code.  More discussion on the topic can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54906434/3513260

Answer (score 43):

You will need to convert your `response` to `json` before you can access `response.body`

> From the [docs](https://github.com/github/fetch)

```
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    console.log('parsed json', json) // access json.body here
  })
```

Comment: Good answer, and thanks for the reference to the documentation. The docs also show what to do if you're using something other than JSON, such as text - it can display the same behaviors and the solution is very similar (use text() rather than json() ).

Answer (score 19):

This requires changes to the frontend JS and the headers sent from the backend.

**Frontend**

Remove `"mode":"no-cors"` in the fetch options.

```
fetch(
  "http://example.com/api/docs", 
  {
    // mode: "no-cors",
    method: "GET"
  }
)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

**Backend**

When your server responds to the request, include the CORS headers specifying the origin from where the request is coming. If you don't care about the origin, specify the `*` wildcard.

The raw response should include a header like this.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Comment: This should be the top answer

Comment: This worked - and should be the correct answer. In my situation, I had a server running w/ Python Flask and by default, it does not return a CORS header. Initially, I was getting around this with JS by including the "no-cors" and then wondering why the response wasn't being parsed. Changing both frontend and backend did the trick.

Answer (score 7):

You must read the response's body:

```js
fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.text()) // Read the body as a string

fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json()) // Read the body as JSON payload
```

Once you've read the body you will be able to manipulate it:

```js
fetch('http://example.com/api/node', {
  mode: "no-cors",
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json"
  }
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    return dispatch({
      type: "GET_CALL",
      response: response
    });
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried that, but I still can get the correct response. Check the Edited question.

Comment: @RazvanIlin Use `.json()` instead of `.text()`

Comment: Sorry, I just realised I copied the wrong snippet in the last example. I was actually using `json()` there, but I get the Syntax error, which I presume gets fired because it cannot convert the response to json

Comment: Tried this and it worked for me. `response.json()` did the magic. Once I had it, I was able to console.log and get my response. Thanks

Comment: Still trying to wrap my head around this `no-cors` mode. I'm in a similar situation. Using variations of the solutions here the no-cors fetch seems to succeed... no x-origin error, and in my network inspector I can SEE data in Preview and Response. But I just can't seem to access the data from the response object passed into my `then`. `json() text()` neither seems to do much. Does an opaque response mean it gets the data then `null`s it so it can't be accessed after completed? :-/

Answer (score 3):

```
fetch("http://localhost:8988/api", {
        //mode: "no-cors",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        return data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        return error;
    });
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
fetch("http://localhost:8988/api", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
})
.then((response) =>response.json());
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
})
.catch(error => {
    return error;
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation would go a long way to help current and future readers understand your response.

Comment: This is actually a very similar example as other answers here. Not sure about SO's policies, but I'm not sure this is allowed

Comment: Only it's not the same.  "Content-Type" is unique.  Too bad it didn't work for me though :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [response.json()](https://github.com/github/fetch#json):

```
fetch('http://example.com/api/node', {
  mode: "no-cors",
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json"
  }
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response.json()); // null
  return dispatch({
    type: "GET_CALL",
    response: response.json()
  });
})
.catch(error => { console.log('request failed', error); });
```

Answer (score 0):

In many case you will need to add the bodyParser module in your express node app.
Then in your app.use part below `app.use(express.static('www'));`
add these 2 lines 
`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it was not cors. For some reason, the client got an empty response body if fetch was invoked from the child component, as soon as I moved the data fetching to the root App component the client got the proper response body. I don't know why, just went with it. If someone could explain it, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was setting the response status code to `204` in my PHP backend. Guess it makes sense since 204 means 'No Content'.