# Response body is null (Fetch request)

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

I am trying to make a request to the bank API, and get its branches in JSON format.

But I get an empty response:

[image: Response]

Although, if I insert the link into the browser, I will get the JSON format.

`https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pboffice?json&city=Ивано-Франковск`

This is how the request works:

[image: Results]

Errors:

[image: Error]

```js
var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  console.log(url);
  
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET', 
        mode: 'no-cors', 
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
      }
        
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      if (response.ok)
      {
        response.json()
      }
      else {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong');
      }
    }); 
}

postData(`https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pboffice?json&city=${address}`, {})
  .then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))) 
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're executing this as a no-cors request.  These are severely restricted and you cannot read the body for it.

See stackoverflow.com/questions/45696999/fetch-unexpected-end-of-input

Also, you're not returning the result of `.json()`, so your function  will in all cases return a promise to `undefined`.

Comment: `response.json ()` doesn't help either

Comment: you're right - that was anothing thing - but the root cause is indeed the no-cors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to fetch data using no-cors when the site doesn't provide right headers then your code will not be able to access the response
a proper explanation can be seen in [how to process fetch response from an 'opaque' type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54896998/how-to-process-fetch-response-from-an-opaque-type)