# How to check if link to image is not broken

Tags: javascript

Is there way to check if link to image is working before adding src attribute to image?
What I have tried:

- First idea was to make ajax call to image src but I cannot be sure that CORS pocily will allow it.
- Adding onError callback into my component. No luck because I use SSR and it causes [problems](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15446)

My use case:
I'm building text editor and user can insert link to image. I want to know if link is ok before inserting it into my model.

Comment: i do not use react but there must be an way to use the old `onerror` attribute

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18837818/4117599
This answer helped me

Answer (score 1):

The other answers/question aren't specifically about cross-domain requests. If you only have to support modern browsers you can use an opaque fetch request which works cross domain and is pretty easy to use.

```js
fetch('http://example.com/your-image-url', { mode: 'no-cors' }).then(() => {
 if (response.ok) {
   // the image exists
 }
});
```

Comment: I cant get response status with `mode: no-cors`.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54896998/how-to-process-fetch-response-from-an-opaque-type. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I am not sure you can - but why? response.ok will be false

Comment: response.ok will always be false with mode: no-cors. So `if(response.ok)` will never be reachable