# HTTP response status is 200, but no response shows

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this simple code to fetch a list of values from my sql table and show them in my `<select>` dropdown.

My **html**:

```
<select class="form-select" id="sel1" name="sel1" style="width: 7em;"></select>
```

My **Javascript**:

```
const from = document.getElementById("sel1");
from.addEventListener("click",function(){
  let $select = $("#sel1");
  $.ajax({
    url: '/paydetails_server.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { "input": "from_periods" }, 
    dataType: 'json',
    cache:false, 
    success: function(response) {
      //console.log(response);
      response.sort();
      let selectedValue = $select.val();
      let html = response.filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) === i).map(item => `<option value="${item}">${item}</option>`);
      $select.html(html).val(selectedValue);
    },
    complete: function() {}
  });
})
```

My **PHP**:

```
if(isset($_POST["input"])){
   if(!$connection)
      echo "Connection to database failed! Please try again";
   else{
      $periods=array();
      $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `YEARMM` from `emp_pp`";
      $result = $con->query($sql);
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if((!str_contains($row["YEARMM"],"S"))&&(!str_contains($row["YEARMM"],"B")))
               array_push($periods,$row["YEARMM"]);
            }
            echo json_encode($periods);
         }
      }
 }
```

Now, when I execute the code in my `localhost` XAMPP server, it works perfectly. But surprisingly, it doesn't work in my live server. I've double checked everything including variables such as host, servername, database name, etc.

I've tried checking for errors in the *Network* tab, but all I get is response status 200. Even when I tried `console.log(response)` nothing shows in the console. Why is this same code working in local server and not in live? Please help me.

Comment: try and var_dump a few variables like periods, result on the php side to check if the code in php is working or not

Comment: Hello can you please check if the response type is <i>opaque<i/>. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54896998/how-to-process-fetch-response-from-an-opaque-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the statement `if((!str_contains($row["YEARMM"],"S"))&&(!str_contains($row["YEARMM"],"B")))` was causing this problem, although, it was running fine in the `localhost`.

Comment: Is it maybe because you are using an outdated version of PHP? Make sure that you are using PHP 8

Answer (score 0):

Check what you get form database, str_contains only verify if result contains letter S or B

Answer (score 0):

When you tell jQuery to parse the data as JSON, it will run the `success` function only if:

- It gets an OK response
- It can parse the response body as JSON

In your PHP you have `echo json_encode($periods)` inside a `while` loop.

If there are more than one values that get looped over, then you have multiple JSON texts mashed together — which isn't valid JSON.

If there are zero entries that get looped over, then you have no JSON — which isn't valid JSON.

Move the `echo json_encode($periods);` statement so it is **after** the `while` loop.