# fetch returns empty body, json works, but plain text doesn't

Tags: node.js, text, socket.io, fetch-api, pihole

I am trying to create a function which return the latest blocked domain from my pihole server.

I first created a JSON call, since the first call I needed was in JSON format, this is all working and I get the data needed.

However, the second function I need is to fetch plain text data and that one doesn't work, it simply returns an empty body `[]`.

This is the function

```
socket.on("pihole_last", function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        let settings = {
            method: "Get",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "text/html"
            }
        };

        fetch('http://domain/admin/api.php?recentBlocked', settings)
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            }).catch(error => {
                return error;
            });;
    }, 1000)
});
```

The JSON function which works looks pretty much the same, the only real different is the header accept and the `res.text()` which should fetch the data in plain text?
The data returned from the URL is a plain text domain, no tags, no nothing.

Comment: I've tried following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840396/fetch-gives-an-empty-response-body - Without any success tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/issues/3980) from the pi-hole GIT, you should provide some form of authentication. The question which you linked in your comment is 5 years old, at that time this was an unintended behaviour.

If I understand correctly the [API description](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/pi-hole-api/1863) one way to authorize should be working with this url:
`http://domain/admin/api.php?recentBlocked?auth=YOUR_TOKEN`

The `YOUR_TOKEN` should be in:

> Authorization & Token required (see WEBPASSWORD in /etc/pihole/setupVars.conf)

Comment: oh, thank you! I was reading this https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/pi-hole-api/1863 which doesn't mention the need for auth for this end point, but looking at the api source file, I can now see it does require it, thank you.