# Fetch API - using response.json() throws an unexpected end of input error

Tags: json, fetch

When using the Fetch API to fetch some JSON from a REST API on my local server and trying to parse the response with `response.json()`, I am receiving an `unexpected end of input` error.

The error is easily reproducible on my local server with the following one-liner:

```
fetch(new Request('http://localhost:9950/RestService/v2/search/find/1', {mode: 'no-cors'})).then(function(response) { response.json(); });

// Output from Chrome console:
// Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
// VM424:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
//     at SyntaxError (native)
//     at <anonymous>:1:128
```

If I view the Network tab, I can see that my request was fulfilled by the server, and if I preview the response I can see that there is valid JSON available there (I double-checked this by copying and pasting the JSON from the Network Response tab in to jsonlint.com). Here is a sample of the response I am getting from the server:

```
{
    "SearchMatches": [{
        "Extracts": ["<b>1<\/b>.txt...", "<b>1<\/b>"],
        "Title": "1.txt",
        "Url": "C:\\TestShare4\\500Docs\\1.txt"
    }]
}
```

If I try to use `response.text()` instead of `response.json()` I get an empty string.

Any thoughts on where I could be going wrong with this?

Note that I have a requirement to not depend on any other frameworks or libraries other than what is natively supported by the browser.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, did you solve this?

Comment: I had the same issue and it was solved by http://stackoverflow.com/a/35291777/3192470.

Comment: 1. Try removing the `no-cors` option and check if this is the issue.
2. If not, what server are you using? I'm curious about the response headers the server sends. Make sure `Content-Type: "application/json"` header is returned by the server