# fetch error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm using fetch API to get data from other APIs this is my code:

```
var result = fetch(ip, {
        method: 'get',
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        country = data.country_name;
        let lat = data.latitude;
        let lon = data.longitude;                       
        //fetch weather api with the user country
        return fetch(`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/efc76f378da9a5bd8bb366a91ec6f550/${lat},${lon}`);
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // access the data of the weather api
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('Request failed', error));
```

but I face error in console:

```
Fetch API cannot load https://api.darksky.net/forecast/efc76f378da9a5bd8bb366a91ec6f550/52.3824,4.8995. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I set headers for the second fetch:

```
return fetch(`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/efc76f378da9a5bd8bb366a91ec6f550/${lat},${lon}`, {
  mode: 'no-cors',
  header: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
  }
});
```

error will gone but `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` do not log anything in console and the fetch not return any value.
what is the problem with my code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20035101/2037335

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is not in your JavaScript code, it is in the API, the server doesn't support cross origin request, if you are the owner of this API you have to add **'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'** header to the response with the allowed origins (* to allow from any origin).
in some cases **jsonp** request may work.

Note: this problem happen only when the request is generated from the browser

Comment: This was the right answer for me as well.  This other answer gives some details on the specific CORS headers you can use:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310394/no-access-control-allow-origin-node-apache-port-issue?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 14):

The issue will not present when "no-cors" argument is used after the url

```
fetch(url, {mode: "no-cors"})
```

Comment: I tried your code but my response will return empty, I don't know why it is occuring, can you give me your feedback?

Comment: Saying this can "fix" anything is misleading. All this does is give you an empty response instead of an error, for whatever that is worth. @huykon225 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35291777/6221448

Comment: Note that `mode: "no-cors"` only allows a limited set of headers in the request. So you can't use "Authorization" header for example. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: Note that this will not work with PUT requests