# Read JSON response from POST request, having JavaScript on frontend and Flask on backend

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, flask, request

My Flask API is supposed to process text query sent in a POST request and respond with a JSON. I send the POST request using the JavaScript fetch API.

```
function getQueryResults(){
    let query = queryInput.value;
    statusTextField.innerHTML = "Processing query \"" + query + "\"...";
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({"query": query}),
        mode: 'no-cors',
    }).then((data) => console.log(data))
}
```

And this is the Flask endpoint (sending a placeholder JSON).

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def get_index():
    return Response(json.dumps((1,2,3)), mimetype='application/json')
```

Strangely, though, the response logged by console.log() contains no body and is of type opaque instead of JSON.

```
Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
body: null
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: "opaque"
url: ""
__proto__: Response
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In flask, if you want to return a response, there is no need to create a `Response()` object since Flask does this automatically on `return`. This should do the trick:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def get_index():
    return json.dumps((1,2,3))
```

This should return a response with status code `200`, and the `JSON` content in the `body`.

A better explanation of this is available in the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/quickstart/#about-responses)

Comment: I tried `return json.dumps((1,2,3))` and it gives the same result. I suspect the problem lies in the JS code, namely Flask sends it correctly but JS reads it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem myself. It was `mode: "no-cors"` that caused it, as says the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169728/redux-fetch-body-is-not-use-with-no-cors-mode/35291777#35291777). I removed `mode: "no-cors"` from JS code and added

```
from flask_cors import CORS
CORS(app)
```

to the backend.