# Response text is always empty event when repose exist

Tags: javascript, typescript

1. I am fetching the PDF via URL, and want to check does that URL will return the document successfully.
2. Sending a request via `fetch()`
3. Get a `response.text()`
4. Want to check does text exist
5. Text is always empty

Cannot figure out why?

`response.text()` always returns empty text, even when PDF document exist in response.

```
  const handleOpenPDF = (url: any) => {
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'no-cors',
    })
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(text => {
    enter code here
        // TEXT is always empty event when response is good
        console.warn('text', text);

        window.open(url, '_blank');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.warn('Error', err);
      });
  };
```

Comment: How about using `response.json()` instead of `res => res.text()`?

Comment: Do you actually need `mode: 'no-cors',`? this can cause a problem sometimes. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169728/redux-fetch-body-is-not-use-with-no-cors-mode/35291777#35291777)

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi I am gonna try to avoid "mode: no cors", but not sure that I will succed

Answer (score 1):

Note that `res => res.text()` means read the body as a string. So it is good idea to use `response.json()` before you access to response. something like this:

```
const handleOpenPDF = (url: any) => {
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'no-cors',
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(text => {
        console.warn('text', text);

        window.open(url, '_blank');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.warn('Error', err);
      });
  };
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840396/fetch-gives-an-empty-response-body) answer.

Comment: This won't work, getting error "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"